# Maven - deploy only static assets

Tags: java, maven, assets

Is there a way to rebuild or reinstall or redeploy static assets using maven (the terminology is failing me here)?

What I want to do is to be able to make a change to a javascript file and deploy it quickly without having to rebuild/install/deploy my entire project.

Thanks!

EDIT:

Right now, in order to get a change to show up I have to execute the following:

```
cd /project/dir && mvn package && \
cd deploy/ && mvn stack-tomcat:deploy
```

Comment: For what purpose?  To have it in your maven repo, or for local development?

Comment: And this is on Linux, if that helps.

Comment: I think it'd be better if you could figure out how to get your IDE to do this instead of maven.

Comment: I don't have enough information.  What do you run in maven to "deploy" to your local environment?  You're probably not doing a `mvn deploy`.

Comment: Actually, sorry, using:

mvn stack-tomcat:deploy

Answer (score 0):

If you are restricted to maven from the command-line, see if the `tomcat:inplace` goal of the [maven tomcat plugin](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-trunk/tomcat6-maven-plugin/inplace-mojo.html) suits your needs.

For local development, you may find the maven support from the various Java IDEs gives you a faster edit-compile-run development cycle (e.g. [m2e](http://eclipse.org/m2e/) and [m2e-WTP](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e-wtp/) for Eclipse) and there is always [JRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/).

Comment: I am restricted to command-line.  I'm running vagrant and doing everything in a Virtual Machine.  tomcat:inplace doesn't seem to update the files :(

Comment: Also, tomcat:inplace fails when I execute from my top-level directory, but passes when executed from my deploy directory (although it still doesn't do the update).